# Removing entries from GPG Keyservers

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg, openpgp, keyserver

I've been using GPG for a few years and my entry at the various directories, such as the Ubuntu's keyserver, is now pretty messy:

```
uid Andy McCall (Andy McCall's PGP Key) <andy.mccall@xxx.xxx>
sig  sig  0463e8da7a2779b7 2021-12-19T12:26:56Z 2026-12-18T11:39:55Z ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  0463e8da7a2779b7 2018-06-05T13:47:23Z 2020-03-21T21:31:35Z ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  0463e8da7a2779b7 2017-07-20T19:12:35Z 2020-03-21T21:31:35Z ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-05-29T12:00:24Z 2019-06-12T12:00:24Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-06-11T12:00:55Z 2019-06-25T12:00:55Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-06-25T00:00:51Z 2019-07-09T00:00:51Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-07-08T12:00:55Z 2019-07-22T12:00:55Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-09-14T00:00:37Z 2019-09-28T00:00:37Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
```

Is it possible to remove some of the earlier entries? For example, I really only need the following entry:

```
uid Andy McCall (Andy McCall's PGP Key) <andy.mccall@xxx.xxx>
sig  sig  0463e8da7a2779b7 2021-12-19T12:26:56Z 2026-12-18T11:39:55Z ____________________ [selfsig]
```

I've have access to my private key, but the specific gpg keychain that some of the earlier entries were made on has been lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common thing to keep history of all the key self-signatures, since they prove what was happening with a key in a certain point in time - i.e. it was valid for a year in 2019, then re-certified in 2020 to extend lifespan and so on. For instance if you generated a signature with that key in 2019, with the single 2021-2026 entry it would not be possible to tell that signature was valid in 2019.